# parar la ejecución de js por unos segundos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Hola muy buenas tardes gente, pasa que tengo un servidor de node en el que tengo unos scripts programados para generar unos reportes diarios.

### Explicación:

Necesito generar reportes diarios de empresas que utilicen la aplicación que estoy creando y almacenarlos en una db, cosa que ya he realizado, pero lo que quisiera es poder pausar el codigo unos segundos, de manera que si hay 2000 empresas no genere los 2000 reportes de tirón (ya que pienso que no puede ser beneficioso en producción para el servidor).

### Problema:

Mi problema es que no he encontrado una forma de pausar el código, he mirado que JavaScript solo tiene en cuanto a tiempo, `setTimeOut` y `setInterval`, y ninguna de las dos me sirve, porque si bien es cierto que la función que esté dentro le puedes manejar el tiempo, el codigo fuera se seguirá ejecutando.

### Contexto:

- Estoy realizando una consulta a la base de datos sobre todas las empresas, y luego las voy recorriendo, la idea es poner la pausa al final de la ejecución del bucle, así:

```
for(let i = 0, n = miArray.length; i < n; i++){
    //mis instrucciones
    (pausa)
}
```

- Estoy utilizando node, js y ts por si les sirve de algo.

Desde ya muchas gracias, a quien me pueda aclarar las dudas !

### Edit:

Me recomendaron que me explicara más sobre porque necesito la pausa y porqué la hago y demás.

Lo que yo hago es que con el módulo de node-cron programo un reporte para todos los días a las 7, lo que hace ese reporte es sacar estadisticas de la base de datos, bastantes estadisticas, y al final los almacena en una tabla especial para almacenar esos reportes

Que pasa, que esas acciones al ser muchas empresas pueden sobrecargar al servidor y a la base de datos, de manera que se queden procesos atascados de otros usuarios que esten haciendo consultas, por eso me gustaría tener una pausa si quiera de 3 o 5 segundos.

Si bien trato de tener un buen codigo que no obstaculize mucho, no me parecería demás agregar una pausa.

Comment: Respuesta rápida: No se puede. Sería bueno que seas más específico en la necesidad de esa pausa, explicar porqué y para qué necesitas detener los procesos de Javascript, tal vez se pueda encontrar una alternativa.

Comment: @Triby,  vale pa, dejame edito la pregunta y trato de explicarme mejor :3

Comment: Perdón, ya vi tu necesidad, pero creo que la pausa no sería tampoco algo bueno para el servidor, en todo caso, deberías procesar solo unos cuantos reportes en cada petición e ir guardando cuál fue la última empresa procesada para comenzar con la siguiente cuando se ejecute nuevamente.

Comment: @Triby podría ser, igualmente esperaré a alguna respuesta, y también me pondré a pensar si hay alguna sokución más viable

Comment: Y si programas la ejecución de cada generación, con eso puedes definir cuándo corre cada cosa?

Comment: O ejecutarlos a una hora en la que el servidor no tenga apenas carga, tal vez?

Comment: Encadena setTimeout's para hacer las consultas, y no para hacer la pausa.

Answer (score 1):

Hola a todos los que se interesaron por la pregunta, después de analizar bien la situación, he llegado a la conclusión de recorrer mi arreglo de empresas NO mediante un for, sino mediante un `setInterval`, la lógica sería la siguiente:

```js
let miArray = [0, 5, 7, 3, 5, 8, 1], //array de mis empresas
      indice = 0,
      interval;

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      //aqui irían todas mis instrucciones
      //en este caso puse un console.log
      console.log('hello world');
      
      //sumo una ejecución al indice y verifico
      //si ya recorrí todo
      indice += 1;
      if (indice >= miArray.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
```

Lo que hago es realizar la misma lógica que un for, solo que dentro de un set interval de manera que ya yo puedo ajustar a mi gusto cada cuanto se ejecutará el código :D

PD: Igualmente seguiré abierto a alguna solución más efectiva :3

Comment: no requieres que haya terminado de ejecutarce el setinterval???

Answer (score 0):

Ya que tienes un cron para la tarea, podrías, en vez de ejecutarlo a las 07:00, ejecútalo entre las 02:00 y las 08:00 (o todo el día), pero, en cada ciclo, hacer **solo** el reporte de las siguientes 200 empresas (ó 100 ó 10, si tardan mucho), teniendo en cuenta para ordenarlas la fecha del último reporte.

Además, dentro del script que genera el reporte, puedes reconocer si ya hay un proceso ejecutándose y evitar hacer más de uno al mismo tiempo.